# Chemical potential $\mu$ controls filling?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, chemical-potential, tight-binding, fermi-energy

If total magnetization of a spin 1/2 system is zero, does it mean that system is at half filling? or chemical potential $\mu=0$? I was trying to show that chemical potential controls filling by taking dispersion of tight binding model: $\xi(k)=-2\cos(k)-\mu=0\Rightarrow k_F=\arccos(-\mu/2)= \pm\pi/2 $ for $\mu=0$. So, in plot of $\xi(k)$ it will imply half filled band, is that the same as half filling? and How does total magnetization being zero implies half filling?

Comment: The filling factor is the fraction of the band which is occupied. Half filling meant that the band is half filled. The magnetization is determined by the difference between the number of filled spin up and spin down states. The chemical potential determines the filling factor but in general has no straightforward relationship with the magnetization. The magnetization can be zero at any filling.

Comment: That is assuming you are talking about a system of spinful fermions. If you are considering the Jorden-Wigner transform between a system of spinless fermions and a spin chain that is a different question